# Relating overlapping simplicial complexes

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, simplicial-complexes

Let $X$ be a simplicial complex and let $A,B\subset X$ be 
subcomplexes such that $C=A\cap B$ is a non-empty simplicial 
complex. Finally, let $C_{\cdot}(X)$, $C_{\cdot}(A)$, $C_{\cdot}(B)$,
$C_{\cdot}(C)$ be the corresponding chain complexes which coefficients in a
field $\mathbb{F}$.

**Question:** Under what conditions does there exist a chain map
$m:C_{\cdot}(A)\to C_{\cdot}(B)$ such
that $m$ restricts to the identity on $C_{\cdot}(C)$?
What if $A,B,C,$ and $X$ are flag complexes?

*Some Basic Observations:*

It seems like simple sufficient condition is that there exist a retraction
$r:A\to C$. However, this does not appear to be necessary. For instance, if we
take

- $X$ to be the simplicial complex given by the faces $(1,2,4),(2,3,4),(3,1,4),(1,2,5),(2,3,5),(3,1,5)$
- $A$ to be the subcomplex given by the faces $(1,2,4),(2,3,4),(3,1,4)$
- $B$ to be the subcomplex given by the faces $(1,2,5),(2,3,5),(3,1,5)$

Then $C$ is the simplicial comlex given by the edges $(1,2)$, $(2,3)$, and
$(1,3)$. While $C$ is not a retraction of $A$, an $m$ satisfying the above 
conditions comes from exchanging the vertices $4$ and $5$.

In general one can write down linear systems arising from the relevant commuting
diagrams and solve them. The solutions haven't been very illuminating. However,
if one considers small random complexes, then more often than not I have been
able to solve the linear system. In a *very* non-rigorous way this seems to
suggest that maybe there are some weak sufficient conditions for such maps to
exist.

Comment: In what terms do you want an answer? If it's just the existence, without any good reason or naturality, this has nothing to do with $X$ and you are just speaking about comparing two short exact sequences in the category of complexes.

Comment: I agree, X doesn't really play any role. I included it simply so people wouldn't complain about $A\cap B$. Categorical proofs, notions, etc. are fine by me and I would be content with (non-constructive) existence statements.

Comment: The kernel of the map $H_*(A \cap B) \to H_*(A)$ must be contained in the kernel of the map $H_*(A \cap B) \to H_*(B)$. I believe that this condition is also sufficient.

Comment: There must be more here that you have in mind but haven't written down: the intersection could just be a single vertex without imposing any seriois constraints on the two subcomplexes!

Comment: @TylerLawson If $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary aside from being connected, and if $C$ is a point, then your condition is immediately satisfied since both kernels are trivial, no? I don't think one can deduce the existence of a chain map in this case, but perhaps I have misunderstood your comment.

Comment: @ViditNanda There is a chain map in that case (you can send all the positive-degree simplies of A to zero and all the points to the point of C); this is covered by case that Paul described where a retraction exists.

Comment: @Tyler Could you elaborate a bit more on your kernel response? The condition seems reasonable, but I'm struggling to produce a proof. More specifically, the necessity of this condition is not too hard to see, but why should it be sufficient?